# Shared memory with mmap returns when writing to mapped memory on linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, mmap

I was trying to figure out shared memory and tried to write a simple program involving a consumer and a producer. I didnt make it to the consumer part and found this weird little problem: The parent will return at the `*spool=3;` with no rhyme or reason on why. Nothing on `dmesg`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PRODUCER_ERROR(msg)         \
    do {perror("Producer Error: " msg "\n"); exit(1); }while(0)

#define SHM_NAME "/my_sharedmem"

void producer();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pID = fork();
    if (pID == 0) {
    // Code only executed by child process
    printf ("Son here\n");
    return 0;
    } else if (pID < 0) {
    perror("Unable to fork\n");
    exit(1);
    } else {
    // Code only executed by parent process
    printf ("Parent here\n");
        producer();
    return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}


void producer()
{
    int fd, d;
    unsigned* spool;

    printf("<<Producer>> started\n");
    fd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR,  S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO ); // FIXED

    printf ("<<Producer>> memory file opened\n");

    spool = mmap(NULL, sizeof(unsigned), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf ("<<Producer>> mmaped to %p\n\tGonna write.\n", spool);
    perror(NULL);

    *spool = 3;
    // msync(spool, sizeof(unsigned), MS_SYNC | MS_INVALIDATE);

    printf("<<Producer>> ended\n");
}
```

EDIT: fixed shm_open mode argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the mode argument to `shm_open` wrong. This is supposed to be a mode specification as for `open`. Probably your version here by conincidence forbids writing to the address, so the process then crashes when you try to write to it.

BTW: you should always check the return of library calls such as `shm_open` and `mmap`.

*Edit:* As I also observed in a comment below, you are also missing to scale the segment to an appropriate size with `ftruncate`.

Comment: Thank you Jens, I fixed that but the problem persists, `sudo ./a.out ; echo $?;` tells me that exist status is 135. :S

Comment: Then attach a debugger to it and see where it bails out.

Comment: as expected I reach this
`51     *spool = 3;
    (gdb) p *spool
    Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7ff9000`

Comment: ah, one thing I see is that you don't size the segment properly. You'd need a `ftruncate` somewhere to adjust the size to something positive.

Comment: that seems to have worked, please edit your original answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

The object you get with shm_open is zero size. You need to allocate some space for it. mmap will allow you to map things beyond their size (both shm objects and files), but you'll crash when you access that memory.

Something like this after shm_open is what you want to do:

```
ftruncate(fd, <the size you want>);
```

You can do it after mmap too, if that floats your boat.